# What exactly happens on the heap when you declare an object?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

taking an Operating Systems course in University and learning more in depth about memory management. I have a question that seems to be unanswered by my textbook. When I declare an object, what exactly happens? For example if I do:

```
String one;
String two;
```

how exactly is the memory allocated on the heap? Or is it not allocated yet since the compiler has no idea what the size will be of that object? What I really want to figure out from this is what if two objects are declared relatively close to each other on the heap, and then upon instantiation, the first is too large and overlaps into the second's memory space?

This may be handled differently in different languages, so preferably I'd like the explanation to be in terms of Java. Thanks!

Comment: You don't declare objects. You declare _variables_.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration will cause nothing to be allocated on the heap.  Both strings are null if you don't initialize them.  In the stack frame in which the method runs there will be two string "pointers" allocated on the stack.

As for your other questions, objects (including strings) can never overlap each other on the heap.  All memory is managed in Java to guarantee that.  Where one object is stored relative to another is not guaranteed and can in fact change during the lifetime of your program as the garbage collector reorganizes your heap.

Comment: Great response, thank you! Does say C++ have the same sort of garbage collection to ensure that overlaps do not happen on the heap?

Comment: Heap management is more than garbage collection... when you allocate two objects in c++ the memory will be separate.  But C++ doesn't have gc (or at least the last flavor of C++ that I used many years ago did not).

Comment: *"Both strings are null if you don't initialize them."* Not if they are local variables. Then they wouldn't have any value. And since you're referring to stack frames, you too are assuming they are local variables, so....